# Update plugins in unicode for 3.06

Tags: plugins, unicode, nsis

I am updating my script to version 3.06 of NSIS.

So I added "Unicode True" in my script, but I have a problem with plugins.

These plugins not of "x86-unicode" version:

- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/FontName_plug-in
- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Marquee_plug-in

If anyone is able to compile and provide dll, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is not really the place for these type of questions. Your best bet is to ask the authors of these plug-ins to create a build for you.

Alternatively you can try the [CallAnsiPlugin plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/CallAnsiPlugin_plug-in), it can call these older plug-ins in a Unicode installer.

Comment: The official forum does not send an email confirmation of registration, so it is impossible to write on it...

Comment: The CallAnsiPlugin plugin works well with Marquee.

Comment: Try the author @ https://vytux.com/main/contact-us/

Answer (score 0):

The modification to add CallAnsiPlugin on the FontName plugin is more difficult.

I moved FontName.dll to the "x86-ansi" folder.
I have converted FontName.nsh, FontReg.nsh and FontRegAdv.nsh ANSI to UTF8.
In FontName.nsh I replaced `FontName::Version` with

```
File "/ONAME=$PLUGINSDIR\FontName.dll" "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\x86-ansi\FontName.dll"
CallAnsiPlugin::Call "*$PLUGINSDIR\FontName" Version 0
```

and `FontName::Name` with

```
File "/ONAME=$PLUGINSDIR\FontName.dll" "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\x86-ansi\FontName.dll"
CallAnsiPlugin::Call "*$PLUGINSDIR\FontName" Name 0
```

But during installation it causes an "CallAnsiPlugin error" and MessageBox "0".
I added this modification :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56854513/15597989
Now print :

```
[ERROR] InstallTTFFont
[ERROR]     error: 0
[ERROR]     FontFile: startest.ttf
[ERROR]     FontFileName: startest.ttf
[ERROR]     Index: Line183.6
```

I discovered that the value 0 is none other than `CallAnsiPlugin::Call "*$PLUGINSDIR\FontName" Name 0`.
So I test to replace (FontReg.nsh line 83) `IfErrors 0 "${Index}-Add"` by `goto "${Index}-Add"` always displays "CallAnsiPlugin error" but the file is installed.

- **I don't know how to remove this false return value !?**
- I saw that CallAnsiPlugin uses a file, this one is not deleted in the temporary folder created by the installer. I don't think this is normal ?

**EDIT :**
My solution that works :
https://github.com/22starworld/FontName-plug-in-NSIS

Comment: The file is not deleted because you prefixed the path with `*`.

Comment: ... `Name 0` should probably not be 0, it needs to be the parameter count.

Comment: In the source code of the plugin `Name` and `Version` is written `name` `version`, this is what causes the error "CallAnsiPlugin error". For the parameter : 1 for version and 7 for name, are values that work.